# `steps_per_epoch=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence`

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running this code in tensorflow: https://github.com/empathy87/nn-grocery-shelves/blob/master/Step%202%20-%20Brands%20Recognition%20with%20CNN.ipynb

```
batch_size = 50
epochs = 15
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                    validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation),
                    epochs=epochs, verbose=1, workers=4, 
                    callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)])

ValueError: `steps_per_epoch=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `steps_per_epoch` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.
```

How I can fix this issue? I've tried to reinstall Tensosflow in Pip install tensorflow and conda install tensorflow.

Comment: Why would you reinstall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the object created by `datagen.flow` doesn't know its size, and accordingly you should specify how many times it is expected to yield values, which you can calculate in conjunction with a *batch size*.

Say you have 100 training points and want to work with a batch size of 30. Then, you would have 4 steps per epoch, calculated in the following way:

```
from math import ceil

n_points = len(X_train)
batch_size = 30

steps_per_epoch = ceil(n_points / batch_size)
```